# Error after ending code that use tkinter with thread

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, server, client, python-multithreading

I am programming a Kahoot!-like game in python with both server code and client code.
I am using tkinter and using multithreading in the program.
Unfortunately I am getting this error: `"Tcl_AsyncDelete:async handler deleted by the wrong thread"`. The error comes after the program disconnects and the window closes.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    matplotlib.use('Agg')

    name = get_user_name()

    topic = get_selected_category()

    SERVER_IP = '127.0.0.2'  # Replace with the server's IP address
    SERVER_PORT = 1100  # Replace with the server's port

    # Connect to the server
    global client_socket
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))

    # Receive and print the client ID assigned by the server
    client_id = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print(f"Connected to the server as Client {client_id}")

    receive_threadd = threading.Thread(target=client_receive)
    receive_threadd.start()
    receive_threadd.join()
    print("the thread closed now")
```

At the terminal, I get:

```
    the thread closed now
    
    Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread

    Process finished with exit code -2147483645
```

I searched online and saw that using the commands: gc.collect()`or`matplotlib.use('Agg')` might help but they did not help.

I put `gc.collect()` after every closing the window with `root.destroy()`,

and the `matplotlib.use('Agg')` I put first in the main function

Does anyone know another command or a method to solve this error?

Comment: `tkinter` is telling you that you can't use it from other threads. Also why do you have a new thread which you immediately call `.join` on?